# Class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver not found in Worklight platform or project

Tags: db2, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Getting the below error even though I have ( db2jcc.jar, db2jcc_license_cu.jar) files in the server/lib directory .

```
 {
  "errors": [
  "Runtime: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver not found in   Worklight platform or project \/GDMSLoginApp"
  ],
 "info": [
  ],
  "isSuccessful": false,
 "warnings": [
  ]
}
```

Datasource properties

```
<!-- Example for using MySQL connector, do not forget to put the MySQL connector library in the project's lib folder -->
            <dataSourceDefinition>
                <driverClass>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driverClass>
                <url>jdbc:db2://xyz.ibm.com:60000/abc</url>
                <user>db2admin</user>
                <password>db2admin</password> 
            </dataSourceDefinition>
```

I am using worklight 6.1.0.1

Comment: So you say that the server can find the `.jar` files, but the server itself says it cannot. Who do we trust?

Comment: Is this in your eclipse env or on the server?

Comment: @user3646990, please do not leave this question unanswered: either delete it or write what you did to resolve it.

Comment: Hello Idan, 

I didn't do anything to resolve this issue. I restarted Eclipse couple of times & it resolved itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to configure the DB2 data sources in Worklight is to use the JDBC 4.0 driver (db2jcc4.jar and its associated license jar files in the same directory). See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333005/no-mbean-found-for-worklight-project).